# authentification user error (admin or simple user )

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an authentification interface where the user must enter his login and password to connect.
the interface that will be displayed is according to the connected login profile (user or administrator)

The user table contains (user, passwd, profile, mail)

Here is my code

In authentification.cs:

```
public Boolean profile_user (string log)
{
   string value = "";
   SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand ();
   cmd.CommandText = "select profile from user where user = '" + log + "';";
   SqlDataReader s = cmd.ExecuteReader ();
   if (s.Read ())
   {value = s ["profile"]. ToString (); }
   if (value == "admin")
   {return true; }
   else {return false; }
}
```

In authentification.aspx.cs

```
login = new profile_user (name.Text)
if (login == true)
{Response.Redirect ("admin.aspx"); }
else
{Response.Redirect ("user_c.aspx"); }
```

The error is always, it executes the part else that is to say that whatever the entered login, always the window of user_c appears

the complete class (authentification.cs) is :

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace my_pfe
{  
SqlConnection conn = new database().connect_utilisateur();
 // database is another class 
public void class new_user(string nom,string pass, string mail , string profile) 
 {insert into instruction}
public Boolean search_user(string login)
 { select requete }
public Boolean profile_user (string log)
{
string value = "";
SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand ();
cmd.CommandText = "select profile from user where user = '" + log + "';";
SqlDataReader s = cmd.ExecuteReader ();
if (s.Read ())
{value = s ["profile"]. ToString (); }
if (value == "admin")
{return true; }
else {return false; }
}
```

i put a breakpoint in value =s["profile"].ToString(); , the value of value is "admin " but admin with a lots of space (value and valeur : the same name)

[image]

Comment: why you use the `new` constructor?

Comment: public void class? really?

Comment: yes, and it's working properly,what is the mistake?

Comment: `void` is one thing and `class` is another thing

Comment: oh no , i'm sorry class is in the wrong place 
i maked it public void ... , that's why i told you it's working

Comment: Do you know why it works? Because syntax errors are hardly highlighted in web programming

Comment: Well, check my answer again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: You must check the values ​​in your database to make sure they do not contain spaces, if not, then you can use [`String.Trim()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx) method that removes all the blanks of a string.

Try:

In authentification.cs:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyPfe
{
   public class NewUser
   {
       private SqlConnection conn = null;

       public NewUser()
       {
           this.conn = new database().connect_utilisateur();
       }

       public void AddUser(string nom,string pass, string mail , string profile)
       {
           //Insert into
       }

       public bool SearchUser(string login)
       {
           //Select requete
       }

       public bool ProfileUser(string log)
       {
           string value = string.Empty;
           var cmd = this.conn.CreateCommand();
           cmd.CommandText = string.Format("select profile from user where user = '{0}'", log);
           var s = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           if (s.Read()) value = s["profile"].ToString().Trim();
           return value == "admin";
       }
   }
}
```

In authentification.aspx.cs:

```
var NewUser = new MyPfe.NewUser();
if(NewUser.ProfileUser(name.Text)) Response.Redirect ("admin.aspx");
else Response.Redirect ("user_c.aspx");
```

Comment: i used a constructor because i call it in another forms
ProfileUser is in .cs class , and the constructor used in forms.aspx.cs

Comment: @Zied.M Well, but you must not, because the constructor cancels the type

Comment: @Zied.M Also, I would like to know if your answer was served

Comment: @Zied.M Using constructors to call methods or variables from other forms is not necessary and at the same time is incorrect

Comment: so, how i do it ? , if i take off the "new" constructor, an error tells me that he does not know the class

Comment: @Zied.M 
This is because you must indicate from where you call the method, please, you could show me the full class of In authentification.cs?

Comment: @Zied.M I'll have to reform all your code, you know?

Comment: first , thank you for your help , second , the same result , i put a breakpoint in value =s["profile"].ToString(); , the value of value is "admin " but admin with a lots of space (maybe my mistake in database ? )

Comment: @Zied.M could you write me what is the string value that throws you? to see what spaces you mean?

Comment: @Zied.M MMM, your database colum or cell value have spaces?

Comment: @Zied.M Check your database, it is the most recommended, and verify that the value does not contain spaces, but, if not, you can use the [`String.Trim()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx) method that removes all the blanks of a string.


I added it to my answer, review it

Comment: it's work , thank you very much for your help (i just add .trim() ) , thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should keep ';' in the query when you are doing db call from asp.net. so try removing that and check if it is working. Also why don't you put a breakpoint and check what value is coming in

```
s ["profile"]. ToString ()
```

Comment: when I put the breakpoint in value = s [profile] .tostring
the value of value is "admin                   "
admin with lots of space,maybe that's why return always false

Comment: Yes. That will be the reason